# While using Colspan, border-right of the last column disappears

Tags: php, html, css, dompdf

I am currently using DOMPDF to convert html to PDF format. When i have multiple columns in one row, the last column has no right border. I read somewhere that it might be because i am using percentage but with pt and px, i still get the same result. I also have another row using 50% as my colspan and it shows the border-right on the last column. Any solution for that one?

This is how it looks:
[image]

Here is another:
[image]

I have also attached an image of how i formatted the code.
[image]

If my question seems unclear and need more details, please let me know and I will make it more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you want to get here but colspan attribute is used to merge to cells in the same column:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Month</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>January</td>
   <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Sum: $180</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you want to set the with of your cells by % use width attribute on the  tag...

Like...

```
 <td width="33%">some text</td>
```

Ref-> http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but even though i tried this method, i was still not able to get a border-right line on the column. If I could paste and image here i would.

Comment: Try removing  the last semicolon in border-width, perhaps thats is confusing dompdf somehow